# Rhythmbox won't play streaming flac files

Tags: rhythmbox, flac

My music collection is stored in flac format on a network-attached Ubuntu Server 12.04 box.  I used to be able to play my music by streaming it over the network to my laptop which runs Ubuntu 12.04 and Rhythmbox.  When I attempt to do so now, my system monitor shows that there is an average of 900kB of traffic on the network, the play indicator in Rhythmbox moves, but I don't get any sound.  The files play just fine with Movie Player and, when I play them with Movie Player, there is only about 250kB of traffic on the network.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too (Ubuntu 12.10 though)

I solved it by making my network box a "proper" mount by editing /etc/fstab instead of a .gvfs mount.

Just create a mountpoint (`sudo mkdir /media/share`) and add a similar line (`sudo nano /etc/fstab`) to your /etc/fstab (assuming the use of smb with no auth):

```
//192.168.1.10/share /media/share cifs defaults 00
```

and then run `sudo mount -a` to mount it

(make sure you have `sudo apt-get install cifs-utils` installed if you're using smb/cifs)